# Init a numpy array with its index

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array Arr and its shape is (100,100,100,3), I want to init this array with its former 3 dimension index, e.g.,

```
[[[  [  0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   1.],
     [  0.,   0.,   2.],
     ...,
     [  0.,   0., 197.],
     [  0.,   0., 198.],
     [  0.,   0., 199.]],
     ....
     [[599., 599.,   0.],
     [599., 599.,   1.],
     [599., 599.,   2.],
     ...,
     [599., 599., 197.],
     [599., 599., 198.],
     [599., 599., 199.]]]]
```

Is there an  efficient way to init this array?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to read this post on how to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several `numpy` tools for generating a mesh, such as `np.meshgrid`.  I'll use `mgrid` since it produces one array.  To make the action a bit clearer I'm using different dimensions.

```
In [410]: np.mgrid[0:2,0:3,0:4]
Out[410]: 
array([[[[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1]]],


       [[[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2, 2]],

        [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2, 2]]],


       [[[0, 1, 2, 3],
         [0, 1, 2, 3],
         [0, 1, 2, 3]],

        [[0, 1, 2, 3],
         [0, 1, 2, 3],
         [0, 1, 2, 3]]]])
In [411]: _.shape
Out[411]: (3, 2, 3, 4)
```

This has put three 'dimensions' first; you want it to be last, so we need to do a transpose.

```
In [412]: np.mgrid[0:2,0:3,0:4].transpose(1,2,3,0)
Out[412]: 
array([[[[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 2],
         [0, 0, 3]],

        [[0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1],
         [0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 3]],

        [[0, 2, 0],
         [0, 2, 1],
         [0, 2, 2],
         [0, 2, 3]]],


       [[[1, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 1],
         [1, 0, 2],
         [1, 0, 3]],

        [[1, 1, 0],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 3]],

        [[1, 2, 0],
         [1, 2, 1],
         [1, 2, 2],
         [1, 2, 3]]]])
In [413]: _.shape
Out[413]: (2, 3, 4, 3)
```

BUT, are you clear as to why you need such a large array?  Maybe a `sparse` mesh would be just as useful.

```
In [416]: np.ogrid[0:2,0:3,0:4]
Out[416]: 
[array([[[0]],
 
        [[1]]]),
 array([[[0],
         [1],
         [2]]]),
 array([[[0, 1, 2, 3]]])]
```

With `broadcasting` these 3 arrays will work just as well as the 4d array.

Don't skimp on the basic numpy reading.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This large array is treated as the 3D points, and I have a transformation matrix to deform the points.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to slice and shorten the array dimensions like this:

```
Arr = Arr[:50,:60,:70]
```

Answer (score 0):

To Init the array, you can use numpy method zeros(), ones(), full(), eye(), etc..

Hear is some ex)

```
a = np.zeros((3,3))
print(a)
# [[ 0. 0. 0.]
#  [ 0. 0. 0.]]
#  [ 0. 0. 0.]]
 
a = np.ones((2,3))
print(a)
# [[ 1. 1. 1.]
#  [ 1. 1. 1.]]
 
a = np.full((2,3), 9)
print(a)
# [[9 9 9]
#  [9 9 9]]
 
a = np.eye(3)
print(a)
# [[ 1.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  1.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

Comment: I don't see how that relates to the question at all...

Comment: Question is changing.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are trying to do is to obtain the indices for each element in a high-dimensional array. Each element has an associated index (or you can think of it as a 1D, 2D, 3D or n-dimensional coordinate in general), check this article: [Array programming with NumPy](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2649-2). For example if you have an array of dimension 3, this means that each element in the array has an associated index of the form (i,j,k), so using Python notation for positions, the first element in a 3-dimensional array has an index (0,0,0) and so on. We can use some of the Numpy built-in functions to get these indices in a new array in which each of its elements is the index associated to each element of the original array. Let's do this with an example first we will define an array:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
```

Now, let's define a function that summarizes the ndarray properties

```
def summarize_ndarray(X):
    print( 'total_elements =', X.size )
    print( 'dimensions =', X.ndim )  
    print( 'shape =', X.shape)
```

And check what is the result for the example

```
summarize_ndarray(A)
```

The output should look like:

```
'total_elements =  8'
'dimensions = 3'
'shape = (2, 2, 2)'
```

The following function gets the indices for each element in a ndarray

```
def get_ndarray_indices(X):
    coordinate_list = []
    for element in np.nditer(X):
        itemindex = list( np.where(X==element) )
        coordinates = [] 
        for index in itemindex:
            coordinates.append( index[0] )
        coordinate_list.append( coordinates ) 
    return np.asarray(coordinate_list, dtype=list,  order='C')
```

The output of this function is a new ndarray that contains the indices of each element in the input X ndarray. Now lets use the function to get the indices of A:

```
A_indices = get_ndarray_indices(A)
```

And then check this new array too

```
summarize_ndarray(A_indices)
```

However the output in this case looks a little bit different:

```
'total_elements = 24'
'dimensions = 2' 
'shape = (8, 3)'
```

Why is it different? It has 24 elements because in your input ndarray you had 8 elements, but each of those has 3 indices (3*8 = 24). It has two 2 dimensions because it has the information related to 8 elements each with an associted 3-dimensional coordinate: (8,3). This kind of solves your problem, but there is an issue because this new ndarray cannot be reshaped/broadcasted to match the shape of the original ndarray, at least using the built-in Numpy functions, check the documentation related to [Broasdcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Hopefully you might find this helpful to solve your original problem.